# How can I restore my iPod touch using a different computer?

Tags: ipod-touch

I've had my 5<sup>th</sup>-gen iPod for a while now, and my computer broke a while back, lost iTunes and everything. Also I can't remember my Apple ID. There was never any need to connect it after I first did to put my music on.

However, I am locked out since typed my password in too many times incorrectly. I have access to my friends computer to restore it, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To restore your device…

1. Put your device into Recovery mode

   1. Turn the device off
   2. Holding the home button, connect it to your computer.
2. iTunes should prompt to restore the device.
3. Follow the instructions.

If you have Find my iPhone enabled, you will need to log in to [iCloud](http://icloud.com/#find) and remove the device from your account before you can restore it.